# libnacl crypto library - how to recover public key

Tags: cryptography, encryption-asymmetric, nacl-cryptography

I use the [nacl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) cryptographic library and need to recover the public key from the
secret key. Is this possible?

This is my somewhat naive attempt:

```
#include <nacl/crypto_scalarmult_curve25519.h>
#include <nacl/crypto_sign.h>

//...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    UCHAR pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    UCHAR sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    char pkhexbuf[2*crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES+1];
    char skhexbuf[2*crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES+1];

    if( crypto_sign_keypair( pk, sk ) != 0) {
        printf( "Failed to generate keys." );
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "public key: %s\n", bytes_to_hex( pkhexbuf, pk, sizeof(pk) ) );
    printf( "secret key: %s\n", bytes_to_hex( skhexbuf, sk, sizeof(sk) ) );

    //reset the public key
    memset(pk, '\0', sizeof(pk));

    //recover public key
    if( crypto_scalarmult_curve25519_base(pk, sk) != 0 ) {
        printf( "Failed to derive public key from secret key." );
        return 1;
    }

    printf( "public key: %s\n", bytes_to_hex( pkhexbuf, pk, sizeof(pk) ) );
    return 0;
}
```

The public keys don't match. Any ideas how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: `crypto_sign` uses Ed25519 (Edwards form curve), `crypto_scalarmult_base` is for key-exchange and uses montgomery form. // You probably shouldn't use the signature code in NaCl in the first place. It's only a prototype.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer! Is there some library you can recommend instead?

Comment: You could take a look at LibSodium, it uses the final Ed25519 variant. But I think they haven't added the key regeneration API you want yet. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/issues/81) and I'd expect that'll be added soon.

Comment: I used libsodium and actually prefer it. But I had to give libnacl a try because there was no package available for my target system.

Comment: A copy of the public key is stored in the second half of the secret key. So, unless you only stored the first 32 bytes returned by NaCl for the secret key, you can simply read the 32 last bytes to get the corresponding public key.